# How to alias a module with Browserify lib in Gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify, commonjs

The Browserify readme describes creating external requires like so:

`$ browserify -r through -r duplexer -r ./my-file.js:my-module > bundle.js`

Then in your page you can do:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  var through = require('through');
  var duplexer = require('duplexer');
  var myModule = require('my-module');
  /* ... */
</script>
```

This works if you want to do use the command line, but I'd like to use Browserify in a gulpfile.  But there seems to be no way to add a name to a module like `./myfile-js:my-module` in the example.  If there's an option for it, I haven't found it.  The only way to require my module in the way that they describe is to do `require(3)` because Browserify seems to give numbers to the modules, but these numbers change and clearly this is not desirable.

EDIT: My current solution is to do this:

```
var shell = require('gulp-shell');

gulp.task('browserify', shell.task([
  'browserify -r ./src/bundle.js:bundle > ./build/bundle.js'
]))
```

This is a workaround and not optimal if I want to take full advantage of the Gulp pipeline.  I'd like to know how this can be done without the command line or, if not, why this is only something that can be done via CLI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`b.require()`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/8f7adc96e3ed59c299d078405a463860f5409ba6/readme.markdown#brequirefile-opts) with `expose` option.

```js
function bundle () {
  browserify()
  .require("./myfile-js", {expose: "my-module"})
  .require("through")
  .require("duplexer")
  .bundle()
  /* ... */
}

gulp.task("browserify", bundle);
```

## Browserify-Gulp integration

The other answers suggest that `vinyl-source-stream` is a requirement here, but that's not necessarily true. You haven't illustrated how you're integrating Browserify and Gulp. You only need `vinyl-source-stream` if you're actually doing some integration between Browserify and Gulp beyond just wrapping a Browserify bundling operation in a Gulp task (which people fairly commonly do), like running a Gulp plugin on the bundled output. For example, you can just do this:

```js
var fs = require("fs");

gulp.task("browserify", function () {
  return browserify(/* ... */)
    /* ... */
    .bundle()
    // But if you're doing something with Gulp here you should use
    // `vinyl-source-stream` and pipe to `gulp.dest()`.
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./bundle.js", "utf8"));
});
```

Comment: I like how you seperated the function out from the task config, do you have your config in multiple files per gulp task?

Comment: You mean like define the task function in a separate file and import it into the gulpfile? I often write it like illustrated here in the same file, but the main reason I did it that way here is because the question is about the Browserify API and doesn't really have anything to do with gulp, so I didn't even really want to mention gulp at all, but did it to try to help the OP see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways that I can think of to accomplish what you're looking for:

**1. Use the .bundle() method:**

It seems like the [.bundle()](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#bbundlecb) method may be what you need. It's pre-built into [browserify](http://browserify.org/). Try experimenting with this code. It allows you to use gulp's `.pipe()` methods.

```
const browserify = require('browserify')
const gulp = require('gulp')
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream')

gulp.task('browserify', function (cb) {
  browserify('./src/bundle.js')
  .bundle() // <- This traverses the /node_modules/ tree to bundle everything ...
            // into 1 giant stream & eventually a single file.
  .pipe(source('bundle.js')) // Creates the "output source" file name,
                             // rather than being the "input source".
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
  return cb()
})
```

Then you should be able to link this file: `./build/bundle.js` to a `<script>` tag like this: `<script src="./build/bundle.js"></script>`.

[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com) links: [vinyl-source-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream), [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify), [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) (You already know about those, but others might not be aware of them yet.)

**2. Make a deep linked alias:**

If you want to make an alias, which deep links into an external JS class (not a CSS class), you'd have to try using a require() method call like this:

```
const bundle = require('browserify').bundle
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
import {bundle} from "browserify"
```

Those last 2 lines assume that a JSON object is being returned from the external module, which is being required/included as a dependency. The return object in that external file, should look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    "default": SomeMainClass,
    "bundle": someExtraFunctionLikeBundle
}
```

*Potential* "Gotchya": If the external dependency doesn't return a JSON object, then the `.bundle` would return undefined. For example, this would prevent the `.bundle` in `require('browserify').bundle` from working:

```
module.exports = function() {...} // instead of module.exports = {JSON}
```

Please let me know if you need additional help with Gulp, after experimenting with the 1st code example. (It's a blend of how `gulp.task()`, `browserify()`, `.bundle()` & `.pipe()` work together, along with your code mixed into it. You should be able to get it to work on your computer.)

Answer (score 0):

When using gulp with browserify, you need to install the `vinyl-source-stream` module. The `-r` flag exposes modules within your bundle externally which they can then call using `require`.

You can configure multiple entries and move your configuration to a      different file,if you just have one entry file, you can instead just pass it to browserify and remove `entries` from the options. The `debug:true` option 
is the same as `-d` from the command line

```
var b = browserify(./app/index.js');
```

Now, you can do this in your gulp config:

```
  var gulp = require('gulp');                                                      
  var transform = require('vinyl-source-stream');                                  
  var browserify = require('browserify');                                          
  var b = browserify({                                                             
    entries:['./app/index.js'],                                                    
    debug:true                                                                     
  });                                                                              

  gulp.task('browserify',function(){                                               
    return b                                                                       
           .require('through')                                                     
           .require('duplexer')                                                    
           .require('./app/lib/my-module',{expose:'my-module'})                    
           .bundle()                                                               
           .pipe(transform('bundle.js'))                                           
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/build'))                                         
 });
```

If you want to expose your module by a different name for use with `require`, use the `expose` option.

Looks like there is a [gotcha](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1014) regarding the use of `non Commonjs` modules or module that do not properly set `module.exports`.

If you want to use the module that you exposed as a `requirable` here from another bundle(assuming you have multiple bundles), you could:

```
b
.external('thorugh')
.external('my-module')
.../*more config*/
.bundle()
.pipe(transform('bundle2.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./app/build')
```

In this case whenever your require `my-module` within `bundle2`, you are reuiring it externally from the `require` in `bundle.js`.

If you want to allow multiple files to be required outside the bundle with a single require call, you can pass them in as an `array`.

```
gulp.task('browserify',function(){                                               
    return b                                                                       
           .require(['through','duplexer'],{expose:'stream-utils'})                                                                                                         
           .require('./app/lib/my-module',{expose:'my-module'})                    
           .bundle()                                                               
           .pipe(transform('bundle.js'))                                           
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/build'))                                         
 });
```

You can look at [Stefan Imhoff's gulp tutorial](http://stefanimhoff.de/2014/gulp-tutorial-5-javascripts-browserify/) and the [browserify API](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) for more information.